# IllegalThreadStateException comes before program contents

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency

I was wondering why the thread exception comes before the contents of the actual program. As far as I understand, the thread exception should come after the contents of the program.

[Output from Simple Thread Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJiyS.png)

#### **Code**

```
import java.lang.*;
public class temp extends Thread {
  private String Name; 
  private int N; 
  temp(String aIn, int aN){
      this.Name = aIn;
      this.N = aN;
  }
  public void run(){
    int lN = this.N;
    String lName = this.Name;
    for (int i = 0; i < lN; i++){
        System.out.println(String.format("Thread %s, i: %d", lName, i));
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    temp ThreadA = new temp("A", 10); ThreadA.start();
    temp ThreadB = new temp("B", 10); ThreadB.start();
    ThreadA.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IllegalThreadStateException` is thrown on second call to `ThreadA.start();` but the stacktrace may be displayed before because exception are outputed through the `System.err` stream which is different from `System.out`. The `System.err` output is design to display output in a timely manner while `System.out` is just a regular output stream.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on VM to VM. to check variation pls try it some number of time eg:10.  it may come in between :)